# Binding element title implicitly has an 'any' type. - error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm receiving the following problem:

> ERROR in src/components/Header.tsx:6:18
>
> TS7031: Binding element 'title' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> 4 |
> 5 |
> 6 | const Header = ({title}) => {
> |                  ^^^^^
> 7 |     return(
> 8 |         
> 9 |
>
> ## {title}

App.tsx contains:

```
import Header from './components/Header'

const App = () => {
return (
     <div className='container'>
       <Header title='Hello' />
     </div>
   )
 }
 
 export default App;
```

Header.tsx contains the following code:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Button from './Button'



const Header = ({title}) => {
    return(
        <header className='header'>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <Button color='green' text='Add'/>
            
        </header>
    )
}

Header.defaultProps = {
    title: 'TaskTracker',
}

Header.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default Header
```

Declaration of the variables.

Comment: `const Header = ({title}: { title: string }) => {` you should use types to type with typescript instead of proptypes

Answer (score 0):

```
import Header from './components/Header'

const App = () => {
return (
     <div className='container'>
       <Header title='Hello' />
     </div>
   )
 }
 
 export default App;
```

You should use types to type with typescript instead of proptypes.

```
import Button from './Button'



const Header = ({title} : {title: string}) => {
    return(
        <header className='header'>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <Button color='green' text='Add'/>
            
        </header>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Credits: @Konrad